# Unserialize() not working for specific data

Tags: php

This code only gives 'a' as a result, but I expect it to return 'touseef':

```
$serialized_data = 's:170:"a:5:{s:4:"name";s:7:"touseef";s:5:"email";s:21:"touseef1819@yahoo.com";s:7:"contact";s:11:"03425001819";s:4:"city";s:9:"islamabad";s:10:"studylevel";s:12:"Intermediate";}";';
echo $objh = unserialize($serialized_data) ;
echo $name=$objh['name'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason your data has been `serialize`'d twice, and you need to call `unserialize` twice to undo that:

```
$objh = unserialize(unserialize($serialized_data));
print_r($objh);
echo $name=$objh['name'];
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => touseef
    [email] => touseef1819@yahoo.com
    [contact] => 03425001819
    [city] => islamabad
    [studylevel] => Intermediate
)
touseef
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/MYZao)